# UITableView row -- Deselecting and changing highlight:NO by selecting another row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm just learning all this stuff, so excuse me if I'm making a glaring error.

I have an array of levels of expertise: @[@"NOVICE", @"INTERMEDIATE", @"PRO", @"ALL LEVELS"];.

The user can select up to two, but if ALL LEVELS is selected, the segue is performed and the setting saved.

What I'm trying to avoid is a user selecting NOVICE and PRO. If NOVICE is selected, I want PRO to be deselected and unhighlighted. And vice versa.

Here's what I have, but I get the error:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *organizeLevelOfPlay = self.organizeDifficultyArray[indexPath.row];

 if ([organizeLevelOfPlay isEqualToString:@"ALL LEVELS"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MinimumNumberOfPlayers" sender:self];

} else if ([organizeLevelOfPlay isEqualToString:@"NOVICE"]){
    [self.organizeDifficultyArray[2] setHighlighted:NO animated:YES]; //I get an error here.
    [self.selectionArray removeObject:self.organizeDifficultyArray[2]];
    [self.selectionArray addObject:organizeLevelOfPlay];
    self.result = [[self.selectionArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectionArray);

} else if ([organizeLevelOfPlay isEqualToString:@"INTERMEDIATE"]) {
    [self.selectionArray addObject:organizeLevelOfPlay];
    self.result = [[self.selectionArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectionArray);

} else if ([organizeLevelOfPlay isEqualToString:@"PRO"]){
    [self.organizeDifficultyArray[0] setHighlighted:NO animated:YES]; //I get an error here.
    [self.selectionArray removeObject:self.organizeDifficultyArray[0]];
    [self.selectionArray addObject:organizeLevelOfPlay];
    self.result = [[self.selectionArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectionArray);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
`-[tableView: deselectRowAtIndexPath:]` function to replace the `-[setHighlighted:NO animated:YES]` one. `@"NOVICE"` and `@"PRO"` may be is `indexpath{0,1}` , `indexpath{0,2}`.

Comment: I think you mean `deselectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. However, my problem wasn't entirely with deselecting the row. I was able to do that with removeObject:. But after I deselect/remove, the row remains highlighted. I need to essentially unhighlight the former row when the latter is selected. And vice versa. Thanks again!

Comment: You can test -[tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:] method in tableview delegate. When you want to unhighlight that one, just in that method, set -[setSelected:animated:] to No in that cell.